# How to check if storing local shared object is allowed by the user or by the browser when in private browing mode?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, local-storage

I am developing a flex component in Flex3 which needs to store some data on the local disk for the future use using

```
 var localData:Sharedobject=SharedObject.getLocal("localdata");
```

Today while i was working on this, eventually i had opened my chrome browser in incognito mode, so the data was not stored and i couldn't restore the data which i has saved earlier.

So i want to know is there any way to check if the local storage is allowed or not; using javascript. Javascript because i want to check it before even my component is loaded. Pls suggest me some ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

`SharedObject.getLocal()` throws an Error when it fails to create SO, so just listen for this error.

**EDIT**

If you need javascript solution you can create a simple Flash/Flex file which will try to create a SharedObject, then it can pass the result (true/false) to Javascript (using `ExternalInterface`).

Then you can pass the result to your main component...

JS can't access flash SharedObjects.

**EDIT 2 **

There is HTML5 localStorage, so you may want to use that one, but from your question I understood you wanted to check if Flash local storage works.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The above solution is useful after i load my component. But i want to check at the beginning itself using javascript

Comment: Ok that would be an option, but don't we have anything in JS just like shared object in as

Comment: Hi gone through one of the sites which gives an online example of the HTML5 localStorage but even if i open that site in private browsing window it was working fine. So i doubt it would be able o serve my purpose.